# My SQL prepared statement to get sum of points by certain id?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to get total number of points back from my MySQL database using JDBC and prepared statements. I currently have

```
private static final String SELECT_TOTAL_POINTS_FROM_LEVEL_BY_CUSTOMER =
        "select sum(points) from level_up where customer_id = ?";
```

```
@Override
public int getTotalLevelUpPointsByCustomerId(int customerId) {
    int points = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SELECT_TOTAL_POINTS_FROM_LEVEL_BY_CUSTOMER, 
            Integer.class);
    return points;
}
```

and my controller method is

```
@GetMapping("/points/{customerid}")
ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public int getTotalPoints(@PathVariable("customerid") int customerId) {
    return service.getTotalPoints(customerId);
}
```

How can i just get the points back from the database with just the customer id?

ERROR BELOW

```
    "message": "StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select sum(points) from level_up where customer_id = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
```

Comment: What is not working? Please read [ask] and provide the necessary information.

Comment: I updated with the error message

Comment: You need to pass in the customer ID. Look for a method on jdbctemplate that you can pass arguments into like this one: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-java.lang.Class-

Comment: That worked, thank you! @NathanHughes

Answer (score 0):

You were using a method that doesn’t allow for passing arguments. Use a method that allows for passing in arguments, like: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-java.lang.Class-